# Understanding $ syntax

Tags: scripting, variable

I am using below command to input by user & want to display it as `3num15`.

*num* --> should be value entered by user. Can you please help me with syntax?

```
echo "Enter the instance number of source system"
read num
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To print or assign a variable when you don't have the benefit of trailing white space you can use `${}` for parameter expansion instead of `$`...

```
echo "12${three}45"
```

For your purposes this should be fine and it's probably the most commonly used approach. Also, note that `echo "12$three"` will work fine. The trailing character is what matters. It must be a character that is not valid in a variable name. Still, it doesn't hurt to use `echo "12${three}"` and I think it improves readability.

Occasionally you may see something like this instead...

```
echo "12"$three"45"
```

Generally I'd avoid that. Alternatively there's printf...

```
printf "12%d45\n" "$three"
```

See `man printf` for details as there are a lot of formats available.

Comment: It's not just whitespace that can terminate an identifier name; the parser greedily consumes any valid identifier character to determine the name. `"12$three-45"`, for instance, would expand `$three`, while `"12$three_45` would attempt to expand `$three_45`.

Comment: @chepner Right. Like my answer says: "...must be a character that is not valid in a variable name". Not the most technical description but I'm trying to avoid getting too technical since OP might be kinda new to this.